# Assambly вызов функции

Tags: c#

Как мне вызвать функцию из загруженной мной dll через Assembly из new Domain

```
Assembly tt = Assembly.LoadFile("E:\\Games\\DC4_PROJECT\\rust_Data\\Managed\\DizzyClient.dll");
        AssemblyName tt2 = tt.GetName();
        AppDomain news = AppDomain.CreateDomain("hack");
        news.Load(tt2);
```

Нужно вызвать из tt функцию *void Ready()* класса *cjb*.

Comment: @pavel1787mego - не пугайтесь - я администратор игрового сервера и решил для себя переделать чит меню ).Дальше меня не куда не уйдет )

Comment: @pavel1787mego rust legacy - так что можете ответить по моему вопросу?

Comment: @pavel1787mego причем тут знание игры - что по загрузке void

Comment: Перечитайте диалог, я сказал - нет не отвечу т.к. не знаю ответа

Comment: @АлексейШиманский всмысле для публики?Щас пока тренируюсь на чит меню - далее по RPC буду для своего сервера делать планины на клиент - это более к unity уже будит относиться - а с основного потока можно сдампить dll

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вызвать метод класса, вам необходимо его сначала создать. Чтобы создать экземпляр вашего класса, вам необходимо выполнить следующую последовательность вызовов. Сначала необходимо создать обертку объекта класса в домене, который вы загрузили dll

```
 ObjectHandle objWrap = news.CreateInstance(tt.FullName, "MyType");
```

Данная функция возвращает объект [ObjectHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle(v=vs.110).aspx), который используется для передачи объекта (в свернутом состоянии) между несколькими доменами приложения.
 Ваш класс *cjb* **должен обязательно наследоваться от класса [MarshalByRefObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx)**, который разрешает доступ к объекту через границы доменов приложений.

После этого, вы можете вызвать функция [Unwrap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap(v=vs.110).aspx) для получения экземпляра класса, созданного в другом домене

```
// Unwrapps the proxy to the MyType object created in the other AppDomain.
MyType testObj = (MyType)objWrap.Unwrap();
```

После этого, вы можете вызвать функцию данного класса.

Comment: жалуется что нету cjb - нужно вызвать cjb.Ready.Init()

Comment: @Сергей, на какой строчке жалуется? cjb - это тип вашего класса ?

Comment: сjb это namespace http://skrinshoter.ru/s/290817/ZTbZaQyP?a

Comment: сjb это namespace

Comment: Сергей, я посмотрел структуру вашей библиотеки,я вам привел в ответе достаточно материала, чтобы вы подставили в нужных местах свои значения

Comment: подскажите что куда подставить - такое вижу в первый раз - жалуется что cjb нету - dll не загружена в проект - просто беру dll по пути и гружу в новый домайн

Comment: да не Ready() - класс Ready() void Init()